# I’ve always seen that Japanese font used for caption, and I have no luck finding it

Tags: font-identification, japanese

[image]

It’s been months of searching, every site containing Japanese font don’t have it. It’s used in anime and anime movies, but today I saw it in a tv show.

Comment: I've tried searching for the font on https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ but I couldn't find anything too similar. Maybe if you try it with a different image of higher quality and more contrast between the background and the font you should be able to find something that resembles it.

Answer (score 1):

It's [ニューシネマ B](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/item?NewCinemaBStd-D) from Fontworks, manually slanted (Japanese fonts usually don't come with oblique). There's also [ニューシネマ A](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/item?NewCinemaAStd-D) which has more "orthodox" shapes, but if I don't see wrong, the glyphs have stencil cut-outs so that I can identify to the other.

[image]

This kind of typeface is categorized as シネマフォント "cinema font", which emulates the lettering style of (traditional) movie subtitles, and habitually used in some storytelling scenes outside movies, too. [Some are freely available](https://ferret-plus.com/7440).